# How to add specific elements (that are strings) in a List of Lists?

Tags: python

This is my List of Lists. Notice that the elements are strings:

```
BTC_USDT = [['16941.19', '0.000796'], ['16941.98', '0.205845'], ['16941.99', '0.011509'], ['16942.34', '0.043801'],
            ['16942.35', '0.253870'], ['16942.36', '0.572059'], ['16942.41', '0.129081'], ['16942.42', '0.017000'],
            ['16942.43', '0.003698'], ['16942.44', '0.048544'], ['16942.52', '0.005100'], ['16942.53', '0.017272'],
            ['16942.56', '0.010200'], ['16942.57', '0.010268'], ['16942.58', '0.010192'], ['16942.59', '0.001071'],
            ['16942.60', '0.011390'], ['16942.64', '0.010115'], ['16942.67', '0.032785'], ['16942.68', '0.062645']]
```

I'm trying to output a sum all the 2-nd elements. And I've come this far:

```
for i in range(len(BTC_USDT)):
    ob_quantities = BTC_USDT[i][1]
    print(ob_quantities)
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting this from some REST API?  Instead of delaying the conversion, I would just use something like [`pydantic`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#data-conversion) to convert the data at the point of ingestion. On the other hand, if you are getting it from parsing a CSV file, I would use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Thank you @suvayu for your suggestion. I will definitly look into pydantic. Learning new things is invigorating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print the sum of all the 2nd elements:

```
total_sum = 0
for element in BTC_USDT:
    total_sum += float(element[1])
print(total_sum)
```

or, to put it another way:

```
total_sum = sum([float(element[1]) for element in BTC_USDT])
print(total_sum)
```

Comment: Thank you @Roniel López. This worked like a charm. I found another way to achieve the results. But your method is faster by 40%